# got 403 when trying to deploy war to tomcat with maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, deployment

already found lots of entries here to fix my issue, but all did not work. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong... I always receive an 403 on tomcat.
I'm using Apache Tomcat Version 7.0.32

**Output:**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Homeserver 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ homeserver >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ homeserver ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (ISO-8859-1 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pi/git/homeserver/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ homeserver ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ homeserver ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (ISO-8859-1 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/pi/git/homeserver/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ homeserver ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ homeserver ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/pi/Maven/homeserver/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ homeserver ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [homeserver] in [/home/pi/Maven/homeserver/homeserver-1.0]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/home/pi/git/homeserver/WebContent]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1759 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /home/pi/Maven/homeserver/homeserver-1.0.war
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ homeserver <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) @ homeserver ---
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/homeserver
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:41.489s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 13 18:19:11 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on project homeserver: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Fhomeserver&war= -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>homeserver</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>Homeserver</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.26</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
   <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/</sourceDirectory>
   <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/</testSourceDirectory>
   <directory>${env.MVNTarget}/${project.artifactId}</directory>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.4</version>
     <configuration>
      <archive>
       <manifestFile>${project.basedir}/WebContent/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
       <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
       </manifest>
      </archive>
      <warSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
      <webXml>${project.basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.1</version>
     <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
     <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
      <configuration>
       <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
       <server>TomcatServer</server>
       <path>/Homeserver</path>
      </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**/etc/maven/settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->

<!--
 | This is the configuration file for Maven. It can be specified at two levels:
 |
 |  1. User Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for a single user,
 |                 and is normally provided in ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml.
 |
 |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
 |
 |                 -s /path/to/user/settings.xml
 |
 |  2. Global Level. This settings.xml file provides configuration for all Maven
 |                 users on a machine (assuming they're all using the same Maven
 |                 installation). It's normally provided in
 |                 ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml.
 |
 |                 NOTE: This location can be overridden with the CLI option:
 |
 |                 -gs /path/to/global/settings.xml
 |
 | The sections in this sample file are intended to give you a running start at
 | getting the most out of your Maven installation. Where appropriate, the default
 | values (values used when the setting is not specified) are provided.
 |
 |-->
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ~/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->

  <!-- interactiveMode
   | This will determine whether maven prompts you when it needs input. If set to false,
   | maven will use a sensible default value, perhaps based on some other setting, for
   | the parameter in question.
   |
   | Default: true
  <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
  -->

  <!-- offline
   | Determines whether maven should attempt to connect to the network when executing a build.
   | This will have an effect on artifact downloads, artifact deployment, and others.
   |
   | Default: false
  <offline>false</offline>
  -->

  <!-- pluginGroups
   | This is a list of additional group identifiers that will be searched when resolving plugins by their prefix, i.e.
   | when invoking a command line like "mvn prefix:goal". Maven will automatically add the group identifiers
   | "org.apache.maven.plugins" and "org.codehaus.mojo" if these are not already contained in the list.
   |-->
  <pluginGroups>
    <!-- pluginGroup
     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
    -->
  </pluginGroups>

  <!-- proxies
   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
   | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
   | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
   |-->
  <proxies>
    <!-- proxy
     | Specification for one proxy, to be used in connecting to the network.
     |
    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>proxypass</password>
      <host>proxy.host.net</host>
      <port>80</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
    -->
  </proxies>

  <!-- servers
   | This is a list of authentication profiles, keyed by the server-id used within the system.
   | Authentication profiles can be used whenever maven must make a connection to a remote server.
   |-->
  <servers>
    <!-- server
     | Specifies the authentication information to use when connecting to a particular server, identified by
     | a unique name within the system (referred to by the 'id' attribute below).
     |
     | NOTE: You should either specify username/password OR privateKey/passphrase, since these pairings are
     |       used together.
     |
    <server>
      <id>deploymentRepo</id>
      <username>repouser</username>
      <password>repopwd</password>
    </server>
    -->
    <server>
     <id>localhost</id>
     <username>admin</username>
     <password>s3cret</password>
    </server>

    <!-- Another sample, using keys to authenticate.
    <server>
      <id>siteServer</id>
      <privateKey>/path/to/private/key</privateKey>
      <passphrase>optional; leave empty if not used.</passphrase>
    </server>
    -->
  </servers>

  <!-- mirrors
   | This is a list of mirrors to be used in downloading artifacts from remote repositories.
   |
   | It works like this: a POM may declare a repository to use in resolving certain artifacts.
   | However, this repository may have problems with heavy traffic at times, so people have mirrored
   | it to several places.
   |
   | That repository definition will have a unique id, so we can create a mirror reference for that
   | repository, to be used as an alternate download site. The mirror site will be the preferred
   | server for that repository.
   |-->
  <mirrors>
    <!-- mirror
     | Specifies a repository mirror site to use instead of a given repository. The repository that
     | this mirror serves has an ID that matches the mirrorOf element of this mirror. IDs are used
     | for inheritance and direct lookup purposes, and must be unique across the set of mirrors.
     |
    <mirror>
      <id>mirrorId</id>
      <mirrorOf>repositoryId</mirrorOf>
      <name>Human Readable Name for this Mirror.</name>
      <url>http://my.repository.com/repo/path</url>
    </mirror>
     -->
  </mirrors>

  <!-- profiles
   | This is a list of profiles which can be activated in a variety of ways, and which can modify
   | the build process. Profiles provided in the settings.xml are intended to provide local machine-
   | specific paths and repository locations which allow the build to work in the local environment.
   |
   | For example, if you have an integration testing plugin - like cactus - that needs to know where
   | your Tomcat instance is installed, you can provide a variable here such that the variable is
   | dereferenced during the build process to configure the cactus plugin.
   |
   | As noted above, profiles can be activated in a variety of ways. One way - the activeProfiles
   | section of this document (settings.xml) - will be discussed later. Another way essentially
   | relies on the detection of a system property, either matching a particular value for the property,
   | or merely testing its existence. Profiles can also be activated by JDK version prefix, where a
   | value of '1.4' might activate a profile when the build is executed on a JDK version of '1.4.2_07'.
   | Finally, the list of active profiles can be specified directly from the command line.
   |
   | NOTE: For profiles defined in the settings.xml, you are restricted to specifying only artifact
   |       repositories, plugin repositories, and free-form properties to be used as configuration
   |       variables for plugins in the POM.
   |
   |-->
  <profiles>
    <!-- profile
     | Specifies a set of introductions to the build process, to be activated using one or more of the
     | mechanisms described above. For inheritance purposes, and to activate profiles via <activatedProfiles/>
     | or the command line, profiles have to have an ID that is unique.
     |
     | An encouraged best practice for profile identification is to use a consistent naming convention
     | for profiles, such as 'env-dev', 'env-test', 'env-production', 'user-jdcasey', 'user-brett', etc.
     | This will make it more intuitive to understand what the set of introduced profiles is attempting
     | to accomplish, particularly when you only have a list of profile id's for debug.
     |
     | This profile example uses the JDK version to trigger activation, and provides a JDK-specific repo.
    <profile>
      <id>jdk-1.4</id>

      <activation>
        <jdk>1.4</jdk>
      </activation>

      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>jdk14</id>
          <name>Repository for JDK 1.4 builds</name>
          <url>http://www.myhost.com/maven/jdk14</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
          <snapshotPolicy>always</snapshotPolicy>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
    -->

    <!--
     | Here is another profile, activated by the system property 'target-env' with a value of 'dev',
     | which provides a specific path to the Tomcat instance. To use this, your plugin configuration
     | might hypothetically look like:
     |
     | ...
     | <plugin>
     |   <groupId>org.myco.myplugins</groupId>
     |   <artifactId>myplugin</artifactId>
     |
     |   <configuration>
     |     <tomcatLocation>${tomcatPath}</tomcatLocation>
     |   </configuration>
     | </plugin>
     | ...
     |
     | NOTE: If you just wanted to inject this configuration whenever someone set 'target-env' to
     |       anything, you could just leave off the <value/> inside the activation-property.
     |
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>

      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>target-env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>

      <properties>
        <tomcatPath>/path/to/tomcat/instance</tomcatPath>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    -->
  </profiles>

  <!-- activeProfiles
   | List of profiles that are active for all builds.
   |
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>anotherAlwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  -->
</settings>
```

**/usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
<!--
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui,manager-script"/>



</tomcat-users>
```

When executing 
mvn -X tomcat:deploy I see following debug output that may the rootcause:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) charset = ISO-8859-1
[DEBUG]   (f) contextFile = /home/pi/Maven/homeserver/homeserver-1.0/META-INF/context.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) ignorePackaging = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mode = war
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = war
[DEBUG]   (f) path = /homeserver
[DEBUG]   (f) update = false
[DEBUG]   (f) url = http://localhost:8080/manager
[DEBUG]   (f) version = 1.1
[DEBUG]   (f) warFile = /home/pi/Maven/homeserver/homeserver-1.0.war
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/homeserver
[DEBUG] No server specified for authentication - using defaults
```

I already used in pom.xml

```
<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
```

that also did not change anything
Does anyone has an idea what is wrong here?

thanks in advance & Kind regards

EDIT:
First thanks for replies I tried all ways but without success.
I now configured my Windows PC for Maven. Even with the changed POM:

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <server>TomcatServer</server>
     <url>http://192.168.34.252:8080/manager/text</url>
     <path>/mycontext</path>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

its still trying to deploy to localhost:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) charset = ISO-8859-1
[DEBUG]   (f) contextFile = C:\temp\homeserver\homeserver-1.0\META-INF\context.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) ignorePackaging = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mode = war
[DEBUG]   (f) packaging = war
[DEBUG]   (f) path = /homeserver
[DEBUG]   (f) update = false
[DEBUG]   (f) url = http://localhost:8080/manager
[DEBUG]   (f) version = 1.1
[DEBUG]   (f) warFile = C:\temp\homeserver\homeserver-1.0.war
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/homeserver  
[DEBUG] No server specified for authentication - using defaults
```

So it seems that it has sth. to do with the pom...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution. I used the wrong goal. Correct would have been

mvn tomcat7:deploy instead of tomcat:deploy
([target definitions of plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html))

By devining that goal maven did not take my tomcat7-maven-plugin.

Just RTFM...

thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `http://localhost:8080/manager` is a default tomcat management app; so you may not want to clash your webapp with that.

Check here   http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/manager-howto.html:

> There are three ways to use the Manager web application.
>
> As an application with a user interface you use in your browser. Here
>   is an example URL where you can replace localhost with your website
>   host name: `http://localhost/manager/html/` .

2nd, you do not need to mention the URL in the pom, in order to fix a URL. Generally, after deployment the URL would be:

```
http://<your_server_name>/<webapp-name>/<welcome page>
```

where webapp-name is usually the war-file-name-without-extension and welcome page is whatever defined in web.xml. In the absence of welcome file name, you need to mention the resource/URL with relative path to app home directory.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [tomcat7-maven-plugin usage docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html), you probably don't need to define a url, as the default (`http://localhost:8080/manager`) should be proper.

More importantly, you'll need to use the same server name for the pom.xml `server` field as you do in the settings.xml `server>id` field to use your login credentials.

Also, if you haven't already, you'll need to install the manager portion of Tomcat as it isn't part of the default install. (run: apt-get install tomcat7-admin)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did all steps you mentioned but still facing the same problem. As I added to my post it seems that the configuration is not read out of the pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to set the URL without the /text at the end of the url.

```
<url>http://localhost:8081/manager</url>
```

Note I'm using port 8081 here.